# Passing values to inner class via template arguments C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

Trying to pass the value to nested class via template agrument,and have some confusion:

```
template<typename A,typename B>
class outter{
    int a;
    T* p;
    ////...////
    template<typename N=int> class inner;

    inner do_something(){
    return inner<a>(p)
    }
}

template<typename T,typename A, typename N=int>
class outter<T,A>::inner<N>{
    sz=N;
}
```

Task is to create an iterator for vector with range control.
For now im stuck in inner class template declaration and passing arguments. Please, i need advance if that possible. Thanks!

Comment: With `template<typename N=int> class inner` you declare that `N` is a *type* not a value. Besides that, templates is a pure compile.time construct, you can't pass any run-time value (like a plain variable) as a template argument.

Answer (score 0):

For the inner class, you have `template <typename N>`, which means that your `N` is a type, not a value, hence, you cannot assign it to a value.

To solve your issue, try having `template <int N> class inner;` and also fix the same way at the bottom `template<typename T, typename A, int N>`

### Edit

Just noticed, that at the bottom you have the inner class definition. What you want this `sz` to be? is it a value or type? In case you want this to be a value, you should write

```
template<typename T,typename A, int N> // this last int determines also the type to be used down below v
class outter<T,A>::inner<N>{
    int sz=N; // this int comes from the upper side ^
}
```

If you want the `sz` to be a type defining the sizes within the inner class, then keep the upper and bottom parts to be `<..., typename N = int>` and put `using` before `sz=N;`

```
template<typename T,typename A, typename N=int>
class outter<T,A>::inner<N>{
    using sz=N;
}
```

If you want to have `N` type and value be specified through templates, please follow this example:

```
template </*outer template params*/>
class outer {
  template <typename SIZE_TYPE, SIZE_TYPE VALUE = SIZE_TYPE()>
  class inner;
};

template </*outer template params*/, typename SIZE_TYPE, SIZE_TYPE VALUE = SIZE_TYPE()>
class outer</*params*/>::inner<SIZE_TYPE, VALUE> {
  using size_type = SIZE_TYPE;
  size_type my_value = VALUE;
}
```

### Edit 2

In case you want to understand what happens here, please read more about the template instantiation.

Comment: Is not help. Key error is: Severity Code Description Project File String Suppression status Error C2992 vector <T, A> :: iterator <N>: invalid or missing parameter list template
My class declaration for now is:

`template<typename A,typename B> 
class outter{  
int a;  
T* p;  
////...////  
template<int N> class inner; 
inner do_something(){  return inner<a>(p)  } 
}  
//outter declaration 
 template<typename T,typename A, int N> 
class outter<T,A>::inner<N>{
  sz=N; 
}`

Comment: Thank's for your reply.I need first. Just trying to pass value from outter class to inner class via template arguments, if that possible.
Yeap,trying by ur first edit,but still have errors like on top.
Course i can realize my case via passing values by constructor argument,but templates are very in generics are very inseresting for me at now. Is that possible to pass value from outter class to inner class via template argument?

Comment: @c_thief I think that is another question and you need to ask it in another post (if don't find the answer on the web). Also, please consider accepting the answer if it does solve your problem. When created the new post, point me and I will do my best to explain